# useEffect causes states to be overwritten in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to implement a wizard where each step will make a rest call to update the object. I have a `ParentComponent` which holds the data that is changed in the form which is in the `ChildComponent`. I found a `useEffect` use case which will me called when the component will unmount (former: `componentWillUnmount` function):

```
useEffect(() => () => saveName(), []);
```

By having an additional `() =>` in `useEffect` I supposedly get the same effect as `componentWillUnmount`.

My parent component stores the data of the form:

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [childKilled, setChildKilled] = React.useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState({ name: "" });
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState({ firstName: "" });
  const [birthdate, setBirthdate] = React.useState({ birthdate: "" });

  const saveName = () => {
    console.log(name);
    console.log(firstName);
    console.log(birthdate);
    //REST-Call
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {!childKilled && (
        <ChildComponent
          name={name}
          firstName={firstName}
          birthdate={birthdate}
          setFirstName={setFirstName}
          setBirthdate={setBirthdate}
          setName={setName}
          saveName={saveName}
          setChildKilled={setChildKilled}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

My child component will call the `saveName` function when it is about to be unmounted. In this example, I trigger the unmount by using the hook `childKilled`. In my real code, I open the next page of the wizard.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const ChildComponent = ({
  name,
  firstName,
  birthdate,
  setFirstName,
  setBirthdate,
  setName,
  saveName,
  setChildKilled
}) => {
  useEffect(() => () => saveName(), []);

  const handleChange = event => {
    switch (event.target.name) {
      case "name":
        setName(event.target.value);
        break;
      case "firstName":
        setFirstName(event.target.value);
        break;
      case "birthdate":
        setBirthdate(event.target.value);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  const handleSave = event => {
    setChildKilled(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input name={"name"} value={name.name} onChange={handleChange} />
      <input
        name={"firstName"}
        value={firstName.firstName}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input
        name={"birthdate"}
        value={birthdate.birthdate}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSave}>save</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

**The problem:** As you can see, I don't just set the value with the hook. I define an attribute inside an object, and this attribute of the object will be set (e.g. `{firstName: ""}`). By doing this, the state of name, firstName, birthdate will all have empty strings (`{name: ""}` , `{firstName: ""}`, `{birthdate: ""}`) when calling `saveName`. Before calling `saveName`, all states seem to be fine. So I guess that the `useEffect` hook is messing up something. And therefore, no attributes can be transmitted.

What causes this issue?

**Note:** I would like to keep the attribute (`{firstName: ""}` and not `""`).

code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rhodes-8w7hg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

I could see in the 'problems' tab in CodeSandbox there was a problem with your React code. This is the following:

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'saveName'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'saveName' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

When I added 'saveName' in the depedency array of your useEffect() hook, I do see the names being logged in the console by your saveName() function.